# How to sync up xmpp server openfire users and iOS APP users

Tags: xmpp

I am using "openfire" as xmpp server. And I am implementing the xmpp client in my APP to provide the chat service to all members. The openfire has its own database said db1. My iOS APP also has its own database said db2. How can I sync up the user tables between these two databases (db1 and db2)? For example, when user signup my APP, I would like to create the same account in xmpp server database. And when user login into my APP service, I would like to have user login into xmpp server automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to synch the databases, you need to write a [custom authentication provider](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html) for Openfire to use db2.

As for the login, you will just have to login to both at the same time.  It can't be done via the other service since that cannot create a connection between you client and the XMPP server.